# Is there a set format on how immediates are shown in RISC-V assembly?

Tags: assembly, riscv, immediate-operand

I'm working on parsing RISC-V assembly, and am working on parsing immediates. Using the `LUI` instruction as an example, I'm seeing examples which write it like `lui t0, 0`, and examples which write it like `lui  t0,%hi(string1)`. Is the 2nd example a psudeoinstruction, and is there any documentation on how each notation works?

Comment: It is a build time function, is a constant at runtime.

Comment: Note that the instructions that use `%lo` have a 12-bit immediate *that is sign extended*!  This means that some values are negative, and they subtract one from the high 20 bits.  Thus, the `%hi` function offsets, by 1, the 20-bit immediate when the 12-bit rest is negative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find documentation for modifiers like `%hi` in the [GNU assembler manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/RISC_002dV_002dModifiers.html).

`%hi(sym)` evaluates to the high 20 bits of the address of the symbol `sym`.  It's no different to the machine from something like `lui t0, 0xabcde`, just that the assembler is computing the value of the immediate for you.

`lui` encodes a 20-bit immediate, so `lui t0, %hi(sym)` is one single instruction, not a pseudo-instruction.